# Where did these numbers come from?

Tags: c#

So I have a code here and what I am tring to do is to get max and min value from string("1 2 3 4 5 6 66") and when I tried to make a char array from this string and get from it max and min I am getting 54 as a max and 32 as a min. HOW?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HighAndLow("1 2 3 4 5 6 66");
    }
    public static string HighAndLow(string numbers)
    {
        char[] liczby = numbers.ToArray();

        int max = liczby.Max();
        int min = liczby.Min();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"{max} {min}");
        return $"{max} {min}";

    }
```

Comment: Because those are the ASCII values of the characters.

Comment: You are reading the corresponding integer values of the characters. You probably want to split the string and then parse each element of that array into integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the char codes, not the values.

Change

```
 char[] liczby = numbers.ToArray();
```

to something like

```
char[] temp = numbers.Split(' ');
int[] liczby = temp.Select(c => int.parse(c)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here

https://www.asciitable.com/

You will see that the character 'c' is decimal 54

and that " " (space) has decimal value 32

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace stack
{
  internal class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          HighAndLow("1 2 3 4 5 6 66");

      }
        static string HighAndLow(string numbers)
     {
         if (numbers.Length > 0)
         {
                var listnumbers = numbers.Split(' ');
                var max = int.MinValue;
                var min = int.MaxValue;
                foreach (var number in listnumbers)
                {
                 var ent = int.Parse(number);
                    max = ent <= max ? max : ent;
                 min = ent >= min ? min : ent;
             }
                Console.WriteLine("max :"+max+" min: "+min);
                return $"{max} {min}";
            }
          return "empty string";
        }
 }
}
```

---

or just replace :

```
char[] liczby = numbers.ToArray();
```

with :

```
var  temp = numbers.Split(' ');
  int[] liczby = temp.Select(c => int.Parse(c)).ToArray();
```